# Can't access phpMyAdmin after installing Varnish

Tags: phpmyadmin, varnish, centos6

phpMyAdmin was working fine, then I installed Varnish. Now I get the 403 Forbidden message when trying to connect to www.myserver.com/phpmyadmin

Apache is listening on 8080 so I tried www.myserver.com:8080/phpmyadmin but firefox says it can't connect to server.

I have tried passing the request through Varnish, putting this in my default.vcl file:

```
sub vcl_recv {

if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
return(pass);
}

}
```

but no joy.

I have the ip address of the machine I am coming from in my phpMyAdmin.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 192.168.100.114
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 192.168.100.114 
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

but I still can't connect. Am I missing something?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot that, at some point, I had bound httpd to the localhost by putting `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080` in httpd.conf. Changing this to `Listen 8080` meant that going to www.myserver:8080/phpmyadmin now worked.